# How to call an async method in a c++ DLL function from a test application

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++-winrt

I am doing a c++/winrt DLL project for a low energy Bluetooth device communication. Almost all the Bluetooth functions are asynchronous. I have a testing c++ console application which will call each of the DLL functions.
My doubt is, how can I hold the test application main thread until the completion of the async DLL function execution.
After checking the completion I need to call the other method.
Please suggest some better ideas.

Comment: The very obvious way is to implement some kind of signalling when the method finishes. How to do that depends on how and why the methods are implemented asynchronously. In other words, there's not enough context to answer your question. It's not even clear what you know about async calls or what you tried etc.

Comment: Instead of `co_await`-ing the awaitable, you can [block the calling thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#block-the-calling-thread) until the asynchronous operation finishes, by calling `get()`.

Comment: Here i am using dllexport to export the c++/winrt dll functions. I am not using any winmd to communicate the c++ console with c++/winrt dll. So the function calls are normal in the interface. Currently i am checking the status of completion of each async functions and wait till it become completed. The 'get()' can be used if the testing application can reference through the winmd.

Comment: Have you read [Asynchronous programming in C++/CX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps) document?

Comment: Why would a document about doing certain things with C++/CX be useful to a developer that isn't using C++/CX?